# In Forge, how to extend Parts node of "Autodesk.ModelStructure" extension, based on "Original Category"

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In Autodesk Platform Services (Forge), the ModelStructure extension is an useful tool for filtering objects based on the object tree hierarchy. However, when dealing with Revit Parts, the ModelStructure tree is limited since the Parts are all together, despite the kind of Part.

The idea is to subdivide further the Parts node, taking into consideration "Original Category" and eventually "Original Family" and "Original Type".

Any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're trying to get the Revit model metadata. You can achieve this by using the APS Model Derivative API.

You can start by using the **GET Fetch Object Tree** which returns a hierarchical list of the object tree. https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-GET/

To further divide the model into categories, you can fetch specific properties of your model using the **POST Fetch Specific Properties** endpoint. https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-query-POST/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Timmy, I'll go with a similiar aproach to the once you propose, but using Viewer specific functions, and with that build a new customized Object Tree. Thanks!